# database insert/update fails with context

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the follwoing Model class:

```
public partial class EmployeeInfo
{
    public int EmployeeInfoId { get; set; }
    public int PolicyYear { get; set; }= DateTime.Now.Year; 
    public DateTime DateFormFilled { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; } = null!;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual JobTitleLookup? JobTitleLookup { get; set; }
    public virtual LocationLookup? LocationLookup { get; set; }
}
  
public partial class JobTitleLookup
{
    public int JobTitleLookupId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual List<EmployeeInfo> EmployeeInfos { get; } = new List<EmployeeInfo>();
}

public partial class LocationLookup
{
    public int LocationLookupId { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual List<EmployeeInfo> EmployeeInfos { get; } = new List<EmployeeInfo>();
}
```

I want to insert the row in the table if the `employeeNumber` and `policyYear` does not exists in the table yet, but if policy Year and employee number does exist, then I want to update the table.

When user fills out an employee form. I have the following code in my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(EmployeeInfo employeeInfo)
{
    await _employeeService.UpdateEmployee(employeeInfo);
}

public async Task UpdateEmployee(EmployeeInfo employee)
{
    _ackContext.Entry(employee).State = !_ackContext.EmployeeInfos.Any(x => x.EmployeeNumber== employee.EmployeeNumber && employee.PolicyYear==DateTime.Now.Year)? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified
     await _ackContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

As soon as I run the above code, I get an error saying:

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Nor sure what am I doing wrong, I also tried this statement and this statement inserts a new row in the table and does not do any update

```
public async Task UpdateEmployee(EmployeeInfo employee)
{  
    _ackContext.EmployeeInfos.Update(employee);
    await _ackContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The above code does not throw any error, but inserts a new row in the table. I can loop through and update each column at a time and that works, but I have several properties in my `employeeInfo` class.

I have several collections inside the class too. I displayed just few in my question above. I am developing this code in .NET Core.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For correct updating EF Core should track entity, better if entity is returned by `DbContext`. Then update will work automatically when you change object properties.

```cs
public async Task UpdateEmployee(EmployeeInfo employee)
{
    var entity = await _ackContext.EmployeeInfos
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.EmployeeNumber == employee.EmployeeNumber && employee.PolicyYear ==DateTime.Now.Year);

    if (entity == null)
    {
        // add new if needed
        _ackContext.EmployeeInfos.Add(employee);
    }
    else
    {
        // set values from detached object
        _ackContext.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(employee);
    }
    
     await _ackContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the entity doesn't contain the key field:

```
_ackContext.Entry(employee).State = !_ackContext.EmployeeInfos.Any(x => x.EmployeeNumber== employee.EmployeeNumber && employee.PolicyYear==DateTime.Now.Year)? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified
```

When you want to update,it doesn't kown which one to update for lack of the key

You could try as below:

```
var exist = _context.EmployeeInfo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeNumber == model.EmployeeNumber && x.PolicyYear == DateTime.Now.Year);
            if (exist != null)
            {
                model.EmployeeInfoId = exist.EmployeeInfoId;
            }
            _context.Entry(exist).State = EntityState.Detached;
            _context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
```

Check the difference:
[image]
[image]